# javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am using JSF+JPA  iam not fix this error:

> javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation
>   constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on
>   callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded
>   ConstraintViolations for details.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "clientCon")
public class ClientController {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Salam");
        clients = new Clients();
    }

    private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    public ClientController() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ClinicProjectPU");
    }

    private List<Clients> clientList;
    private Clients clients;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public Clients getClients() {
        return clients;
    }

    public void setClients(Clients clients) {
        this.clients = clients;
    }

    public List<Clients> getClientList() {
        this.clientList = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Clients.findAll").getResultList();
        return clientList;
    }

    public void createClient() {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(clients); // the only interesting method
            em.flush();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("created");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<h:form>
    <fieldset>
        <h:panelGrid  columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Ad" style="color: #0099cc"/>
            <h:inputText class="form-client" value="#{clientCon.clients.name}" />
            <h:outputText  value="Soyad" style="color: #0099cc" />
            <h:inputText class="form-client" value="#{clientCon.clients.surname}" />
            <h:outputText value="Telefon" style="color: #0099cc" />
            <h:inputText class="form-client" value="#{clientCon.clients.phone}" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <div class="btns">
            <center><h:commandButton action="#{clientCon.createClient()}"  value="Saxla" style="width: 60%;margin-top: 5%;border-radius: 5px;color: #ffffff;background-color: #0099cc" /></center>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</h:form>
```

---

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(BeanValidationListener.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:748)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectClone(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4310)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4287)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4229)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at controller.ClientController.createClient(ClientController.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To know what caused the constraint violation, you can use the following validator and logger.

```java
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    
Set<ConstraintViolation<Clients>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(clients);
    
if (constraintViolations.size() > 0 ) {
  System.out.println("Constraint Violations occurred..");
  for (ConstraintViolation<Clients> contraints : constraintViolations) {
    System.out.println(contraints.getRootBeanClass().getSimpleName()+
    "." + contraints.getPropertyPath() + " " + contraints.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Put the logger before persisting the entity. So between

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
//here goes the validator
em.persist(clients);
```

Compile and run. The console will show you, just before the exception stack trace, which element(s) caused the violation(s).

You can but should catch your try block containing any persistence method with `ConstraintViolationException` (to avoid further problems and/or inform the user an error occurred and its reason). However, in a well built system there shouldn't be any constraint violation exception during persistence. In JSF, and other MVC framework, the validation step must be totally or partially done at the client side before submit/persistence. That's a good practice I would say.

Comment: Thank you very much for this rich answer.

Comment: very useful!! thanks! I wonder why they don't just put the violation outright on the stacktrace already.

Comment: There is a feature request for that: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519573

Answer (score 4):

This is another way from correct answer on Sujan Sivagurunathan, i wrote not in comment because i dont have 50 reputation.

If you have AbstractFacade.java write this on create method

```
public void create(T entity) {        
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    javax.validation.Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(entity);
    if (constraintViolations.size() > 0 ) { 
       System.out.println("Constraint Violations occurred.."); 
       for (ConstraintViolation<T> contraints : constraintViolations) {
            System.out.println(contraints.getRootBeanClass().getSimpleName()+
            "." + contraints.getPropertyPath() + " " + contraints.getMessage());
        }        
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);              
    }
}
```