# glassfish HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error with jpa one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, one-to-many

i am trying to create a bidirectional one to many relationship.

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Company.FIND_ALL, query = "select c from Company 
})
public class Company {
public static final String FIND_ALL = "Company.findAll";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String email;
private String name;
private String phoneNumber;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
private List<Place> places;

private long millisSince1970;
private boolean deleted;

public Company() {

}

@PrePersist
public void addMillisPrePersist() {
    millisSince1970 = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
    deleted = false;
}

@PreUpdate
public void addMillisPreUpdate() {
    millisSince1970 = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
}

}
```

Place class:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Place.FIND_ALL, query = "select p from Place p")
})
public class Place {
public static final String FIND_ALL = "Place.findAll";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private Type type;
private String email;
private String name;
private String city;
private String address;
private String phoneNumber;
private String latitude;
private String longitude;
private String workingHours;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private Company company;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "place")
private List<SpecialOffer> specialOffers;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "place")
private List<Event> events;

private long millisSince1970;
private boolean deleted;

public Place() {

}

@PrePersist
public void addMillisPrePersist() {
    millisSince1970 = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
    deleted = false;
}

@PreUpdate
public void addMillisPreUpdate() {
    millisSince1970 = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
}
}
```

And here is simple resource:

```
@GET
@Path("{companyId}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Company getCompany(@PathParam("companyId") int id) {
    return entityManager.find(Company.class, id);
}
```

In my database i have `Company` and `Place` tables, in the `Place` table i have a foreign key column named `company_id`, so when i try to get some `Company` which has some corresponding `Place` glassfish returns http status 500 internal server error without any exception, and server logs are empty, thus i can not debug or understand the cause of this problem. If i try to get the company which doesn't have any places it returns it without any problem. So what am i doing wrong?

P.S. i think my question is similar to this one [Glassfish: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error without any exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844480/glassfish-http-500-internal-server-error-without-any-exception) which unfortunately doesn't have any responses

Comment: Look at the Server logfiles. There must be an exception

Comment: @jens looking at the domains/domain1/logs/server.log i can say that there are no exceptions, and i have only one domain.

Comment: You have other logfiles?

Comment: @jens no, before this problem i already had http 500 but i could see the exception in log file or IDE console, however here log file is empty as well as the IDE console

Comment: @Asiat I'm sitting with this issue, how did you debug glassfish without it printing anything to the Log?

Comment: @AjOtto i couldn't find a solution to this problem, i just switched to another application server.

Comment: @Asiat Hey, I don't remember exactly what caused the issue but i've solved it by fixing my annotations - there was a problem in my entities and I've switched from 'Resource-Local' to 'Jta' which caches much better and loads faster - also there's support for multiple entity managers,


Did you deploy to a different server and it worked fine?
an issue I can see is that you cannot have a Place without a Company, but you can have a Company without a Place - because of that Nullable = False